# Batch: for loop on files issue with symbol in name

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, symbols

Why does this for loop not work for files with "!" in the filename? And how can I make it recognize files with "!" or other possible symbols that may not work.

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set my_dir=C:\Test
set my_ext=txt
cd /d !my_dir!
for %%F in ("*.!my_ext!") do (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%K in ('
        forfiles /M "%%~F" /C "cmd /C echo @path^|@ext"
    ') do (
        echo "%%~K": %%L
        set list=!list!%%~K;
    )
)
```

I get a returned message like this, with the ! missing from the output.

```
ERROR: Files of type "C:\Test\My file name has an explanation point here.txt" not found.
```

Comment: Because you've used `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of your script, and kept it enabled throughout. the `!` character is special when delayed expansion is enabled.

Comment: What is the point of using `forfiles` here? does `%%~xF` not suffice for you for some reason?

Comment: @Compo okay that sort of makes sense. Unfortunately I have to use delayed expansion or I can't access and set my variables inside the for loop.

Comment: @aschipfl to be honest I just found an example and modified it. I first tried using just forfiles but couldn't get it to set a variable. %%~F will work in the for loop as I need the full file path, not just the extension. Although this method will include a file with ! in it's name and not produce any error, although the ! is still not included in the output. I think it would be preferred to error out for my use case... another program will use this list of files, so better if they all actually exist.

Comment: @Compo I got it to work by removing EnableDelayedExpansion and setting my variable in the loops like this `set "list=%list%%%~K;"` Thanks!

Comment: you can remove the entire `forfiles` loop and simply `echo `%%~xF`

Comment: `set "list=%list%%%~K;"` inside the loop is definitely not going to work because `%list%` always expands to the value present before the whole loop even starts to iterate, hence you *need* delayed expansion, but you need to toggle it on and off to safely expand `for` meta-variables (like `%%~K`) and you have to make sure to transfer `list` to the next loop iteration then; or you write `call set "list=%%list%%%%~K;"` as an alternative solution, which is slower and introduces problems with the `^`-symbol…

Comment: @aschipfl you're right. It was working sort of, but I wasn't testing with enough files. The call set method won't work either because I don't have control over how the files are named. Can you explain how to toggle delayed expansion on and off in order to transfer the variable to the next iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of something which may work for you:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "my_dir=C:\Test"
Set "my_ext=txt"
CD /D "%my_dir%" 2> NUL || GoTo :EOF
Set "list="
For %%G In ("*.%my_ext%") Do (Echo "%%~fG"^|%%~xG
    If Not Defined list (Set "list=%%~fG") Else (
        For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%H In ('Set list'
        ) Do Set "list=%%I;%%~fG"))
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(!list!
EndLocal
Pause
```

If you wanted each of your filepaths to be doublequoted, then a couple of small changes are all you need:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "my_dir=C:\Test"
Set "my_ext=txt"
CD /D "%my_dir%" 2> NUL || GoTo :EOF
Set "list="
For %%G In ("*.%my_ext%") Do (Echo "%%~fG"^|%%~xG
    If Not Defined list (Set "list="%%~fG"") Else (
        For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%H In ('Set list'
        ) Do Set "list=%%I;"%%~fG""))
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(!list!
EndLocal
Pause
```

*It is important to note, especially because you're using full paths for each of them, that there is a limit to the size of a user defined environment variable of 32767 characters. This means that depending upon the number of matching files in `%my_dir%`, you could exceed that maximum. In both examples, you can obviously remove the `Echo "%%~fG"^|%%~xG` part, if you didn't really require it.*

Comment: This works perfectly! I'll keep the variable limit in mind. If it becomes an issue I might re-do this code in python. One question, is the open parenthesis intended in the last Echo line? I've not seen that before.

Comment: Yes it is intended @Archer, without it, if there were no matching files, the content of `!list!` would stil be undefined. This means without the `(` you'd effectively just have `Echo`, and the result of that would be you'd receive the status of that command, either `ECHO is on.`, or `ECHO is off.`. You've probably seen `Echo.` before, to do this, but generally I have found that `Echo=` and `Echo(` are more robust.